# Proving $T^2=T_0 \iff R(T)\subset N(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Posting here for other people to draw inspiration, but definitely also for proof-verification. Any tips on formatting/formalizing would be greatly appreciated, as well as actual corrections of the proof!

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation and $T_0$ be the transformation that sends every input to $0$. Then, $T^2=T_0 \iff R(T)\subset N(T)$.

***Proof:***

- Suppose $T^2=T_0$, and let $a\in R(T)$. Then $T(a)\in T(R(T))=T(T(V))=T^2(V)$.
  $T^2=T_0 \iff\forall_{x\in V}(T^2(x)=0) \iff T^2(V)=\{0\}.$
  As $T(a)\in T^2(V) = \{0\}$, it follows that $T(a)=0 \implies a\in N(T).$

**(1)** Since $a\in R(T) \implies a\in N(T)$, it follow that $R(T)\subset N(T)$.

- Suppose $R(T)\subset N(T)$. Then $T(R(T))\subset T(N(T)) = \{0\}$. It then follows that $T(R(T))=\{0\}.$
  $\{0\}=T(R(T))=T(T(V))=T^2(V) \iff \forall_{x\in V}(T^2(x)=0)$

**(2)** As $\forall_{x\in V}(T^2(x)=0)$ it follows that $T^2=T_0.$

From **(1)** and **(2)** we can conclude that $T^2=T_0 \iff R(T)\subset N(T)$. $\tag*{$\Box$}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That definitely works. Alternately, you could use equivalences all the way:

- $T^2=T_0$
- $\forall x\in V\bigl(T^2(x)=0\bigr)$
- $T^2[V]=\{0\}$
- $T\bigl[T[V]\bigr]=\{0\}$
- $T\bigl[R(T)\bigr]=\{0\}$
- $\forall v\in R(T)\bigl(T(v)=0\bigr)$
- $\forall v\in R(T)\bigl(v\in N(T)\bigr)$
- $R(T)\subseteq N(T)$

Comment: That's actually an interesting approach! That way you don't have to bother proving both ways.